# Why doesn't this `declare-function` form suppress 'Warning: the function is not known to be defined.'?

Tags: elisp-macros

Here's [my `declare-function` form in file A](https://github.com/vermiculus/magithub/pull/218/commits/43ee33df45ccd656ee65f8f96982a5f1b8b1463a#diff-855ec7ceff8e38595bac651e2b1ca52cR648):

```
(declare-function 'my-function "file-B" (my-func-arg &optional args))
```

and here's [the definition of `my-function` in file B](https://github.com/vermiculus/magithub/blob/43ee33df45ccd656ee65f8f96982a5f1b8b1463a/magithub-issue-tricks.el#L17):

```
;;;###autoload
(defun my-function (my-func-arg &optional args)
   ...)
```

During compilation, I receive [the following warning](https://travis-ci.org/vermiculus/magithub/jobs/331251676#L878):

```
file-A.el:1223:1:Warning: the function ‘my-function’ is not
    known to be defined.
```

It was my understanding that when the byte compiler sees the `declare-function` form, it assumes from there on that `my-function` *is* defined.  Running `M-x check-declare-file` on `file-A` succeeds, so what's gone wrong?

Comment: I think it's because you're quoting `'my-function`, which is unnecessary because `declare-function` is a macro. See [`(elisp) Declaring Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declaring-Functions.html).

Comment: @Basil doh! yes, it's a macro. I must've been blind to that little quote – let me give it a shot.

Comment: @Basil Yep, that was it; do you want to convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: I don't claim authority on this, but IME simple support issues like this can just be closed as they offer limited help to other users. I lack a strong opinion on this.

Comment: Too bad there's no 'too localized' option like that which existed on TeX.SX years ago…

Comment: @Basil Please make your comment an answer and Sean -- please accept it even if you think that this is a simple support issue. I think the problem may hit others too and the question - answer scheme is the cleanest and simplest way to help in that situation. I think closing is more appropriate if one has a very special problem which is of no general interest and the answer is of no value for others. The short answer from Basil's comment is sufficient. Copy & paste will do. (Side note: A search produced no direct duplicates. But, maybe I didn't look hard enough.)

Comment: @Tobias Fine by me :-)

Comment: Arguably, the byte-compiler should emit a warning when the first arg of `declare-function` is not a symbol.    You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't quote the first argument to `declare-function`, as it is a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html); i.e. it receives its arguments implicitly quoted and unevaluated. See also [`(elisp) Declaring Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declaring-Functions.html).

This should work:

```el
(declare-function my-function "file-B" (my-func-arg &optional args))
```